# Is It Important To Specify Data Types For Speedy NumPy computations?

Tags: python, numpy, types

I have a python script that I have coded almost entirely in NumPy for a numerical simulation and prior to running my script I have not specified the datatype for any of the variables. I tried to figure out a way to speed up my code and eventually stumbled upon Numba where the importance of datatypes becomes a lot more transparent. As someone new to programming and scientific computing, the idea of specifying datatypes prior to the computation was not something I really thought much about because even when I don't specify the types, NumPy is able to execute just fine.

So what I am wondering is if it's actually more efficient to be specifying datatypes explicitly in the initial construction of my NumPy arrays, and if so, why is that the case? If not, why? If possible, it would be nice for the answer to generalize outside of the specific case of NumPy if at all possible.

Comment: In `numba` specifying dtypes helps it compile the code efficiently.  But with `numpy` arrays, dtype is an integral part of the array specification.  Every array has a dtype, whether you set it or not.  You might want to test some small, typical, calculations to see whether choosing `float32` instead of the default `float64` helps, but I suspect it doesn't make a big difference.  An remember `dtype` is a property of an array object, not a variable.  We don't "intialize" variables in Python (in the `c` code sense).

Answer (score 1):

By default, NumPy selects the appropriate data type according to the function used. For example, if you call `numpy.array((1, 2, 3))` the resulting array will have integer type, but if you call `numpy.array((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))` the resulting array will have float type. Therefore, most of the time it doesn't matter whether you specify explicitly the `dtype` of the array. In some very specific cases, you might be able to use a data type with less bytes to speed up computations a bit, but in my experience the speedup is negligible and the resolution loss is not:

```
arr = numpy.array((1.0, 2.0, 3.0), numpy.float32)
```

Calculations on this array (as opposed to the default `numpy.float64`) will be a bit faster, assuming no type casting will be necessary.